# Angular ngInclude - Does it make multiple requests for content?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to work out how some code is working, it uses angular throughout the front end.

When the page first loads a div with ng-include should be in the dom but its src url is a call to a js function that returns undefined on page load.

```
<div id="test_div" ng-include="getUrl()"></div>
```

When I check the dom the entire element is not on the page. After a search button is pressed some other calls happen and the call to getUrl() will return a valid url from that point on, which returns html content from the server.

It is only then that the div appears in the dom and it now has a class added to it of class="ng-scope".

I dont understand how this is happening, does ng-include continue to request a resource until it is avilable?

I couldnt find this information in the documentation.

Comment: dont pass function() in angular expression, it will run multiple times, by design.

Comment: When you pass a function in an angular expression it will be called for each digest cycle, since Angular needs to check if the value is updated. Hence in your example it will be called multiple times.

Comment: Patrick can you create an answer and possibly link to a tutorial or post that explains what is happening and I could accept it.

Comment: Is it this diagram? http://blog.bguiz.com/post/60397801810/digest-cycles-in-single-page-apps/

Comment: @berimbolo: Yep, that's pretty much how it works.